# Read data from the device using Modbus

Tags: c#, modbus

I have a device working on the Modbus protocol. It is necessary to implement a poll of this device. I have a function to read data, but how to see what the device returns? Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM6");
    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 450;
    mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 3000;

    mySerialPort.Open();
    mySerialPort.Write(ReadHoldingRegister(02, 1508, 1), 0, 8);
    mySerialPort.Close();           
}

public static byte[] ReadHoldingRegister(int id, int startAddress, int length)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[8];
    byte High, Low;

    data[0] = Convert.ToByte(id);
    data[1] = Convert.ToByte(3);
    byte[] _adr = BitConverter.GetBytes(startAddress - 1);
    data[2] = _adr[1];
    data[3] = _adr[0];
    byte[] _length = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
    data[4] = _length[1];
    data[5] = _length[0];
    myCRC(data, 6, out High, out Low);
    data[6] = Low;
    data[7] = High;
    return data;
}}
```

I tried to read using this function.

```
byte[] ReadExact(Stream s, int nbytes) {
var buf = new byte[nbytes];
var readpos = 0;
while (readpos < nbytes)
    readpos += s.Read(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
return buf; }
```

And reading from the stream:

```
byte[] response = ReadExact(serial.BaseStream, 9);
```

Then I tried to use nmodbus, but I can not find anywhere how to return data. Here is my code:

```
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
        serialPort.PortName = "COM6";
        serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort.Open();
        ModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(serialPort);
        byte slaveID = 2;
        ushort startAddress = 1508;
        ushort numOfPoints = 1;
        ushort[] holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveID, startAddress, numOfPoints);
        Console.ReadKey();
        serialPort.Close();
```

Comment: Just use [NModbus](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4) instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the SerialPort read methods?

Comment: Yes, I can not understand. Because when I try to use ReadByte, I get something wrong.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to read the data back. Also what do you mean by _" I get something wrong"_ - if you get an exception - give the full message. Note that you should edit your question to add the extra code - it can be formatted properly that way.

Comment: If you do update the question & want me to help - add a comment starting with @PaulF - that way I will be notified, otherwise I am unlikely to see the question again.

Comment: @PaulF I added a change to the question

Comment: Your NModbus example looks correct - I am not sure what you mean by _"can not find anywhere how to return data"_ - the ReadHoldingRegisters method returns an array that you have assigned to _"holding_register"_. Check the contents of that array. Have a look at the [API manual (not sure if up-to-date)](http://ftp.icpdas.com/pub/cd/8000cd/napdos/modbus/nmodbus/nmodbus_api_manual_v1.2_en.pdf) for exception handling to check for errors that may occur.

Comment: Latest help file is here : https://github.com/Maxwe11/NModbus4/blob/master/NModbus.chm but that does not give any example code.